# why bootstrap includes 18-30px difference between container width and screen size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap has these styles:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
```

Why are there the following differences?

```
768-750 = 18
992-970 = 22
1200-1170 = 30
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margin_(typography)

Comment: thanks, but aren't the margin's already set by `cols` classes?

Comment: There are no margins on the column classes, it's padding. It's aesthetics as per the designer -- you can change in LESS, SASS, or the customizer at GetBootstrap.com.

Comment: yes, I know that those margins are achieved using paddings. By 'margins' I was referring to the space the article talks about. So what you're saying is that those differences between min-width and container are there for no particular reason?

Comment: This is the only thing I've ever seen on GitHub about it: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13363. I would guess that it's so that there's some decent looking white space on either sized of the .container.

Comment: See http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works

Comment: @cvrebert, yeah, the article you mentioned is really good, but unfortunately it doesn't reveal anything about the question.

Comment: @Christina, thanks, but it's not it. There's a lot of mysterious about bootstrap :)